# onchange and oncontextmenu is not the same with onclick

Tags: javascript

```js
//Main Function to Fire
document.getElementById("div").onchange = function(){
  alert("Changed");
}

//Manipulative Functions
document.getElementById("chklabel").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("inp").value = 'Clicked';
}

document.getElementById("chklabel").oncontextmenu = function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (document.getElementById("chk").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("chk").checked = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("chk").checked = true;
  }
  document.getElementById("inp").value = 'Context';
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <label id="chklabel" for="chk">Checkbox Toggle</label>
  <input id="chk" type="checkbox">
  <input id="inp" type="text">
</div>
```

what i want to do is when the div is changed in this case by the checkbox in case checked or unchecked to `alert("Changed")` problem here is

- **left-click on label -> Checkbox(Checked) -> alert("Changed");**
- **left-click on label -> Checkbox(Unchecked) -> alert("Changed");**

but for rightclick

- **right-click on label -> Checkbox(Checked) -> Nothing**
- **right-click on label -> Checkbox(Unchecked) -> Nothing**

but i want the rightclick change to toggle the div `onchange` and alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can manually trigger an event by using [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

`document.getElementById("div").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));`

```js
//Main Function to Fire
document.getElementById("div").onchange = function(){
  alert("Changed");
}

//Manipulative Functions
document.getElementById("chklabel").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("inp").value = 'Clicked';
}

document.getElementById("chklabel").oncontextmenu = function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (document.getElementById("chk").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("chk").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("div").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
  } else {
    document.getElementById("chk").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("div").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
  }
  document.getElementById("inp").value = 'Context';
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <label id="chklabel" for="chk">Checkbox Toggle</label>
  <input id="chk" type="checkbox">
  <input id="inp" type="text">
</div>
```